# show loader when dom is rendering in Angular

Tags: angular, rendering

I have a large sized form that I need to show using ngif if user checks on a checkbox.

The problem is that the form takes some time to render to the screen. If the user toggles the checkbox repeatedly, the application hangs for a bit before it can show the form.

I need to either pause user interactivity or show a loader that indicates that the form is rendering. Any help?

Comment: I think a loader is the better choice.  If the UI goes dead on the user they will think your app crashed.  Have a look at Angular Material which has some nice loaders you can use.     This one:  https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/overview for example

Comment: Is there any way we can listen to DOM when it is rendering?